# How to delete a tag in Nodejs from an XML Content?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml

I am loading the XML content from a file and want to delete a specific node from this content. Is there a proper way to do it in Nodejs?

For example I have this xmlString:

```
<sports>
 <cricket Team="England">
  <Players Name="EAA" Flg="0"></Players>
  <Players Name="EAB" Flg="1"></Players>
 </cricket>
 <cricket Team="India">
  <Players Name="IAA" Flg="0"></Players>
  <Players Name="IAB" Flg="1"></Players>
 </cricket>
 <cricket Team="Aus">
  <Players Name="AAA" Flg="0"></Players>
  <Players Name="AAB" Flg="1"></Players>
 </cricket>
</sports>
```

Here, want to remove `cricket`.

Comment: `cricket` is a tag. Are you sure you want to remove that?

Comment: Yes, its just an example. 
I want to be able to remove a tag like cricket, or sports, whatever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better to first parse the XML into a javascript object, manipulate it, then convert it back to XML if required, here's a code to delete the "cricket" objects, you'll need to install xml2js to get it working:

```
    var xml  = `<sports>
 <cricket Team="England">
  <Players Name="EAA" Flg="0"></Players>
  <Players Name="EAB" Flg="1"></Players>
 </cricket>
 <cricket Team="India">
  <Players Name="IAA" Flg="0"></Players>
  <Players Name="IAB" Flg="1"></Players>
 </cricket>
 <cricket Team="Aus">
  <Players Name="AAA" Flg="0"></Players>
  <Players Name="AAB" Flg="1"></Players>
 </cricket>
</sports>`


var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
parseString(xml, function (err, result) {

  delete result.sports.cricket;
  var builder = new xml2js.Builder();
  var xml = builder.buildObject(result);
    console.log(xml);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the regex in JavaScript as shown below:

```js
xmlString = '<sports><cricket Team="England"><Players Name="EAA" Flg="0"></Players><Players Name="EAB" Flg="1"></Players></cricket><cricket Team="India"><Players Name="IAA" Flg="0"></Players><Players Name="IAB" Flg="1"></Players></cricket><cricket Team="Aus"><Players Name="AAA" Flg="0"></Players><Players Name="AAB" Flg="1"></Players></cricket></sports>';

console.log(xmlString.replace(/<[//]{0,1}(cricket|\/cricket)[^><]*>/g,""));
```

Comment: I tried it out, 
but it removes for example: "<sports>", but not "</sports>" 

So, it have some problems removing </..>. 

But still, this idea is good

Comment: Thanks, its great

Comment: Is there also a way to insert a variable in this regex? 

removeTagByTagName: function (xmlString, tagName) {
        return xmlString.replace(/<[/]{0,1}(tagName|\/tagName)[^><]*>/g,"");
    }

Answer (score 0):

The code removes xml blocks of certain tag names, e.g. .... and auto close tags .e.g.

usage:
removeXmlElements (hay, [...elements])

e.g.
const result =removeXmlElements ("hello **world**", ["b"])

the result will be hello

```
const hay = `<a>yes yes<w:sdt id="a">hello world</w:sdt>nono</a> 
<w:tcWa id="2"/>aaaa`

const removeXmlElements = (hay, elements) =>{

    const isTagAutoClose = (hay, tag) =>{
       let ret = false
       //situation one with no attributes
       const regexp1 = new RegExp(`<${tag}/>`);
       ret = regexp1.test(hay)
       if (!ret) {
           const regexp2 = new RegExp(`<${tag} [^<>]*?/>`);
           ret = regexp2.test(hay)
       }
       return ret
     }

     let ret = hay    
    
    for (const item of elements) { 
       
        //situation one ele with no attibutes
        const isAutoClose = isTagAutoClose(hay, item)
        if (isAutoClose) {
            const regexp1 = new RegExp(`<${item}/>`, "g");
            ret = ret.replace(regexp1, "")
            //situation two ele with attributes
            const regexp2 = new RegExp(`<${item} [^<>].*?/>`, "gs");
            ret = ret.replace(regexp2, "")

        }else {
            const regexp1 = new RegExp(`<${item}>.*?</${item}>`, "gs");
            ret = ret.replace(regexp1, "")
            //situation two ele with attributes
            const regexp2 = new RegExp(`<${item} [^<>].*?>.*?</${item}>`, "gs");
            ret = ret.replace(regexp2, "")
        }

    }

    return ret
}

console.log(removeXmlElements(hay, ["w:tcWa", "w:sdt"]));
```